# OverlapCircle won't find player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to give to the NPCs of a game I'm working on the ability to "sense" when the Player is near. I've made this script and, for reasons unknown, the bool "found" stays false and, when I automatically set it to true, it reverts back to false (it still sends the player position to the goTo script, so at least that works). Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
public class NPCLookForPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public bool found;    //player found
public float awareness;   //how large is the circlecast
public int keepLooking; //for how much time, after losing sight of the player, he tries to keep on looking for him
public GameObject player;  //variable to lock on to the player
int timer;    //variable to decrement while player isn't in line of sight

NPCGoToScript goTo;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    goTo = GetComponent<NPCGoToScript>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //he's always looking for the player
    Collider2D coll = Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position, awareness);

    //if the player is found, keep looking for him
    if (coll.gameObject == player)
    {
        found = true;
        timer = keepLooking;
    }

    //if the player was found, 
    if (found)
    {
        timer = timer - 1;    //less time to look for the player
        goTo.newPosition(player.transform.position);
    }

    //if the player is out of sight for too much time, stop looking for him
    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        found = false;
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;

    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere((Vector2)transform.position, awareness);
}
```

}

Since someone has made me notice that the values of the variables aren't written in the code, let me be clear: I'm working on unity, this script has public values that can be modified by the inspector, which is very usefull since this script has to be used for different kinds of NPCs. So the values are not zero. awareness = 5f and keepLooking = 20. The player field does have the player GameObject.

Comment: are you sure you arent detecting yourself? or, that you seem to be comparing a collider2d to a gameobject?

Comment: @BugFinder positive, I've tried many times walking in an out of the circle's radius but the inspector always shows found= false

Comment: @BugFinder ok, I got what you meant, if(coll==player) was wrong and I corrected it, but it still isn't working

Comment: Then its time to do some debug logging.  Your overlapcircle ia probably picking up something else and returning that to you instead - get it to print out  what it is hitting.. either then, change it to mask to only pick up players, or, use overlapcircleall and check if one of the things is a player..

Comment: @BugFinder could you kindly explain to me how to use overlapcircleall and check if one of the collisions is a player please? I've tried doing it before but the code came out too heavy. Thanks for your help

Comment: it returns an array, just itterate over the array, and if player is one of them, tada,

Comment: it's working, thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting initial values for any of your fields :).

**timer** is declared but never set to anything so essentially it equals 0.  Also **awareness** (your radius) is never set either so is 0.0f by default.

So your code...

1. Executes the `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` with a radius of zero (i.e. no circle)
2. Skips the logic in the `coll == player` statement cause there is no circle to collide with the player.
3. Skips the logic in the `found` statement cause **found** of false
4. Then executes the logic in the `timer <= 0` statement cause the **timer** is 0 (was never defined)
5. Continues to set **found** to false every frame, forever and ever and ever, into the long good night

The player getting the the transform data should only happen whe you manually set found to true in the inspector and then only for one frame cause it reverts back to false in the very next statement.

You need to give your fields value greater than 0.

Comment: They aren't set in the code because, since I have to use different values for every npc, I set them directly in the inspetor in unity. awareness has a value of 5f, while keepLooking has a value of 20